# Scala type mismatch in map operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying a map operation on a Spark DStream in the code below:

```
val hashesInRecords: DStream[(RecordKey, Array[Int])] = records.map(record => {
      val hashes: List[Int] = calculateIndexing(record.fields())
      val ints: Array[Int] = hashes.toArray(Array.ofDim[Int](hashes.length))
      (new RecordKey(record.key, hashes.length), ints)
    })
```

The code looks fine in IntelliJ however when I try to build I get an error which I don't really understand:

```
Error:(53, 61) type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Int]
 required: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Int]
      val ints: Array[Int] = hashes.toArray(Array.ofDim[Int](hashes.length))
```

This error remains even after I add the type in the map operation like so :

```
records.map[(RecordKey, Array[Int])](record => {...
```

Comment: I believe the error is here: `hashes.toArray(Array.ofDim[Int](hashes.length))`. The [`toArray` _method_](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#toArray:Array[A]) does not accept any input Array _(but it does need an implicit `ClasTag` for building the array)_. You may just remove the argument an leave Scala built the **Array** or, if you want to speed up the code by copying the **List** elements to an already instantiated **Array** use [`copyToArray`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#copyToArray(xs:Array[A]):Unit)

Comment: By looking at the [_source code_ of `toArray`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L286) it uses [`copyToArray`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L251) internally, so there is not much difference. - I would just call `toArray`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez If i just called the non paramentrized toArray id get an array of Objects, not Ints right?

Comment: no, you would get an **Array** of **Ints**, if you look at the type signature of the method, it says that it returns an `Àrray[T]` - _where `T` is the type of the **List**_. In other words, If you have a **List** of **Ints** you get an **Array** of **Ints**. For that it needs an _implicit_ `ClassTag[Int]`, which explains the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem, also it avoids the call of `List.length` which is **O(*N*)**, and uses `Array.length` instead which is **O(*1*)**.

```
val hashesInRecords: DStream[(RecordKey, Array[Int])] = records.map { record =>
  val ints = calculateIndexing(record.fields()).toArray
  (new RecordKey(record.key, ints.length), ints)
}
```